# JdbcIO.read() - query partitioning

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-beam

My requirement is to select millions of rows from a MYSQL database using the JdbcIO API. I am using JdbcIO version 2.7.0.

### **Sample code:**

```
pipeline.apply(JdbcIO.read()
        .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
        .create(jdbcProperties.getProperty("driver"), 
                jdbcProperties.getProperty("url"))
        .withUsername(jdbcProperties.getProperty("username"))
        .withPassword(jdbcProperties.getProperty("password")))
        .withQuery(query.toString())
```

The performance of the query is slow, as the JDBC connection is kind of a single threaded operation at the worker node level.

I checked the source code for the readAll() method and they are also not supporting parallel read/write operations.

By contrast, Spark has the following properties to parallelize the JDBC read/write operations - **numPartitions, partitionColumn, lowerBound, upperBound**.

**Do we have a similar option in the JdbcIO API to partition the query and parallelize the JDBC read/write operations, so that bulk data retrieved from the database is processed in parallel ?**

Comment: This is a great question; I am wondering the same.